# <h:selectBooleanCheckbox> doesn't work if put inside <ui;repeat>

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, primefaces, mojarra

There are couple of limitation(defect?) of jsf which causes this issue.

```
    <ui:repeat value="#{myBean.myAttrs}" var="attr">
          <h:outputText value="#{myBean.selectedObj.values[attr.name]}" 
            rendered="#{attr.dataType=='Text'}"/>
          <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myBean.selectedObj.values[attr.name]}"
            rendered="#{attr.dataType=='Boolean'}"/>
           .... render other data type like list, date etc.
    </ui:repeat>
```

First "render" property limitation in jsf, the component is still processed even render is false. This causes every attr type in ui:repeat will try to evaluate value for each output component. i.e. value of selectBooleanCheckbox will try to evaluate for date type. If render is false, the component won't be rendered eventually. Everything is fine even with this issue if without selectBooleanCheckbox(2nd issue).
Second issue, selectBooleanCheckbox will always assume the input value is Boolean type. So evaluate value (due to 1st issue) will fail for date type.

Is this code sniper common for display different data type dynamically in JSF?  I tried to configure customization renderer, converter for the selectBooleanCheckbox. But it still fail with data type convert exception.  Any idea?  How to change the default "expectedType" for selectBooleanCheckBox from "Boolean" to "Object" just like other JSF input component.

--Update: the issue is only for mojarra instead of myfaces.

Comment: What Mojarra version are you using? Older versions have indeed known state saving issues with `<ui:repeat>`.

Comment: It is latest mojarra 2.1.7. Our project can't switch to myfaces since the known issue(faces messages not rendered) -https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TRINIDAD-2227

Comment: Anyone see similar issue? I can't find any defect reported for majorra. So I still doubt sth i did wrong.  I found the source code in majarra which hardcode Boolean data type for boolen component.   
Value.HolderRule.java
  public void applyMetadata(FaceletContext ctx, Object instance) {
           UIComponent c = (UIComponent) instance;
           c.setValueExpression("value", attr.getValueExpression(ctx, ((c instanceof UISelectBoolean)? Boolean.class: Object.class)));
       }

Comment: What does Primefaces have to do with this?

Comment: Submit SR for mojarra  http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-2559?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel&focusedCommentId=348741#action_348741